# Is there a way to make aptana 3 autoreload when i make changes to a py file in a django project?

Tags: django

Aptana makes it open in --noreload mode automatically because not doing so causes python instances to remain open or something like that, is there anyway to bypass this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's not possible to auto-reload .py files within an Aptana Python run/debug configuration (which is what I'm assuming you're doing to get access to the call stack for debugging). I've been using Aptana for Python development for a couple of years, and I've yet to see a way to do this. if someone knows how, please share!